# argument of type {context, fn} has undefined or null fn with sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux

I use redux and sagas, when i do my API call, the api response is 200 but i'm getting in the log "argument of type {context, fn} has undefined or null `fn`".

Why? Basically my yield put(actions.postToApiSuccess(resp.data.json)); is not called

[image]

[image]

```
import { all, takeEvery, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import actions from './actions';
import omit from 'lodash/omit';
import axios from "axios";

function run(data){

  return axios ({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://creaz:81/agents/api/pages/subscribe',
      data: {
        data
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Accept": "application/json" }
  });
}

function* postToApi(payload) {
  
  try {
    const resp = yield call(run(payload.payload.data));
    yield put(actions.postToApiSuccess(resp.data.json));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(error);
    yield put(actions.postToApiError(error));
  }

}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actions.POST_TO_API, postToApi),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//change this this line of code, should work fine

From >>>
const resp = yield call(run(payload.payload.data))

To >>>
const resp = yield call(run,payload.payload.data)